# String Comparrison not working

Tags: string, perl, loops, equality

I have an until loop which is supposed to display a menu for someone to enter commands until "x" is entered, exiting the loop. Problem is, that never happens. Anyone know why?

```
until($cmd eq 'x'){
    system('clear');
    main_menu();

    print "Enter a command choice from above, or \'x\' to exit the program\n";
    $cmd = <STDIN>;

    if ($cmd ne 'x'){
        process_cmd($cmd);
    }
}
```

The process_cmd function should only be called if a command other than "x" is entered, then the until loop shouldn't iterate again, as that condition becomes satisfied.

Comment: Young padawan, your string has a newline. Use the [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html), you must.

Comment: Matt is right. chomp ($cmd = <STDIN>) is what you want